# After I deploy my project he can’t find the images and log

Tags: html, reactjs, image, deployment

When I work in local I wrote in img src='./logo/logo.svg', because It want work when I wrote the hole way, my images stay in public folder but components folder in src folder.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C1zCqVUclMUsn1SgVQs5YW_T5S85wnjeSeh7jdN0Ywg

I tried to show the hole way and run build and deploy, also I try to put the images in googledisk, but also dont work. Also I tried to change the way in manual on github.io, but still((

src='../../public/logo/logo.svg'

https://voloxatyj.github.io/abz.agency/

Comment: did you try /logo/logo.svg ?

Comment: In local I do like you wrote and its work, but when deploy she cant find them. Thats a problem(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use import:

```
import logo from './logo/logo.svg'

<div>
 <img src={logo} />
</div>
```

Comment: do like you say and get the same error when I’m trying to writing tha hole way, you may see https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V5qdgN-oAxLFyDoJA7uphBlF_C-wTe4aD4Xbm7Tsovs

Answer (score 1):

[image]Instead of using

```
src='../../public/logo/logo.svg'
```

use

```
src='logo/logo.svg'
```

Comment: For logo its really help, I do the same way to other images but for them its not work. You may see https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tXeM5MqZ-65kfUOK_oiaqBil3eiHuasEi0w0icoJdGE

Comment: can you provide link of that web page ?

Answer (score 0):

It’s work when I import all images like component, as write my friend upper) Do this and all would be good)

> import logo from './logo/logo.svg'